# .htaccess and images redirect from another server

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Wonder, I'm bulling a system that I will be able to upload to another hosting with domain just 1 file like: index.php and this file will calling to some other file in another server and print the html he got.

so right now, there is a option to do, when I print:

```
<img border="0" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="" />
```

something in the .htaccess or something will now that this image is on:

```
http://www.masterdomain.com/images/template_1/
```

?

I tried:
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.masterdomain.com/images/template_1/$1

but it's not working very well,
I need also css so I believe it's the same command.

Thank you all!

Comment: Your question is impossible to understand. Please reformulate it.

Comment: building some system that you can open a lot of sites just by uploading 1 file: index.php, in this index.php he will print some html code, I want that google think that all the images and the css is on the domain and no link to the primary server..

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://www.masterdomain.com/images/template_1/$1 [NC,P]
```

The P flag will proxy your request to the masterdomain server

Comment: Not Working, I have already tried this. I think this is because that the .htacess loaded and just at the end he loading the html from the primary server.